# Caesar Cipher in C adds extra characters to 2d string array

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

I have seen similar answers on stack overflow, but none had the same problem as I do. My problem with this simple caesar cipher encryption function is that for the position [2] of my encrypted array (and only at position[2]) a (^3) symbol, followed by the encrypted string at position [3] gets concatenated to it.

```
    void encryptIDS(char login_ids[5][6])
    {
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int stop = 0;
      int alphabet_count = 0;
      int numbers_count = 0;
      char lower_case[27] = {'a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
      'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
      char numbers[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
      '9'};
      char encrypted_string[5][6];
      for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      {
         for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
         {
           alphabet_count = 0;
           numbers_count = 0;
           stop = 0;
           while (stop == 0)
           {
              if (login_ids[j][i] == lower_case[alphabet_count])
              {
                 encrypted_string[j][i] = ((((login_ids[j][i]-'a')+7)%26)+'a');
                stop = 1;
            }
            else if (login_ids[j][i] == numbers[numbers_count])
            {
                encrypted_string[j][i] = ((((login_ids[j][i] - '0')+7)%10)+'0');
                stop = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                alphabet_count++;
                numbers_count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[0]);
printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[1]);
printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[2]);
printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[3]);
printf("debug : %s", encrypted_string[4]);
}
```

the content of login_ids is "vc136","jc580","cl274","tm361,"ns792"
when printing them out they all encrypt nicely except for the troublesome 3rd one as "cj803", "qj257", "js941^3at038", "at038", "uz469"
this is quite mistifying as the string at position [2] has more than 6 characters, which it shouldnt have. 
Any and all feedback is appreciated, including comments on how awful my code is, or if this question is misusing the website in any way. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have 27-long array for letters?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you are [NULL-terminating](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) the strings.

Comment: Also, use library functions. `isalpha`, `isdigit` will reduce your code few orders. Another thing, is that your letters and numbers can be defined as `char numbers[] = "0123456789";` But you will not need these anyway if using library.

Comment: numbers[numbers_count] seems like its reading out of index values for letters larger than the 10th letter in the alphabet, im debugging your code now though and ill post it fixed soon

Comment: I would add this line after the declaration of `encrypted_string`: `memset(encrypted_string, 0, sizeof (encrypted_string));`.  This will initialize the members, and get rid of the strange behavior that you're seeing.

Comment: @Bwebb actually, initialization is the problem, and you just got lucky in your test run. Look carefully at the wrong result Alberto presented: it is string 3 concatenated with string 4! This is the result of `encrypted_string` never being null terminated - when it is sent to `printf` it keeps running and prints the next string separated by whatever garbage that happen to be in memory the array is now occupying.

Comment: very useful information, I would just like to add I mistakenly gave the alphabet 27 letters as I am used to the spanish alphabet having the 'Ñ' letter. I have taken the suggested changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be offended, but your code is awful as you suspected :)

But, this is an opportunity to learn why, and how you can fix it, so I will explain int detail:

You code has 4 main problems.
Two of them break the program and will cause it to print garbage or crash with segmentation fault, depending on the memory layout when your program runs.
The other two let your program print the correct answer, but make it horribly inefficient by wasting memory and processor cycles.
If this is an assignment you are being graded on, you will loose score, and if you are learning for yourself, this is a bad programming practice.

**Problem 1:**
As already pointed out in the comments, you must always NULL terminate your strings in C.
If you don't, functions like `printf` that use them will keep printing memory content until they encounter a random NULL value or until your program crashes.

So, in your outer `for` loop, you must add a line like this:

```
for (j = 0; j < 5; i++) {
    //code to do the cypher

    encrypted_string[j][5] = '\0'; //add terminator to string
}
```

Alternatively, you may initialize the array the way Bwebb shown you:

```
encrypted_string[5][6] = { '\0' };
```

This will put zeros in all array cells in advance. But, if you use this method, be careful not to overwrite the last cell of a string in one of your loops!

**Problem 2:**
Also pointed out by Bwebb, you increment `alphabet_count` and `numbers_count` together, but use `numbers_count` to index a smaller array.

This means for any letter from k to z your program will access memory it should not touch when it performs the second `if` check.

This problem will go away on its own however, if you fix the following two problems and structure your code correctly.

**Problem 3:**
You waste memory with two big arrays: the letter array and the number array.
You don't need them! Since you calculate the cypher correctly, you must already know how letters and numbers are represented in a computer, so you don't need to compare your string to the contents of these arrays one by one.

You know letters are a continuous range, so just use a single `if`.

**Problem 4:**
You waste time with the `while` loop.
This is part of the same issue stated in problem 3 - you don't need to loop!
Just make one comparison to see if the current character is in the range of letters and if it is not, make another comparison to see if it is in the range of numbers.

Your code will work correctly if you fix only problems 1 and 2, but if you fix 3 and 4 your code will be shorter and easier to read and understand, so there will be much less chance of any other errors sneaking in.

Here is how to do this:

```
//this is the inner loop, the outer loop over j stays the same
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //check if this is a letter - a range between a and z inclusive:
    if (encrypted_string[j][i] >= 'a' && encrypted_string[j][i] <= 'z') {
        encrypted_string[j][i] += 7; //encrypt through shift by 7

        //rotate to beginning of alphabet if needed:
        if (encrypted_string[j][i] > 'z') encrypted_string[j][i] -= 26;
    } else if (/* do the same thing for numbers) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note, that I split your encryption calculation in to two lines: this is also to make it easy to read and understand.

You can still use your original calculation:

```
encrypted_string[j][i] = ((((login_ids[j][i] - 'a') + 7) % 26) + 'a');
```

But readability is an important aspect of any good code.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but in that for loop in problem 4, why does j get incremented if the loop uses i as the counter? also dont I need two for loops to go through both rows and columns in the 2d array?

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake and I will edit to fix it. It should be `i` as you said.
Yes, you do need the outer loop to go over all the strings, but since there is nothing to fix there, I only posted the inner loop, where I made changes.
The rest of your code is fine so I didn't copy it.

Comment: I fixed the code and some typos, but looks like that removed the "excepted" mark... Didn't know SO worked like that, bug guess it makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void encryptIDS(char login_ids[5][6]);

int main(void) {
    char login_ids[5][6] = {{"vc136"},{"jc580"},{"cl274"},{"tm361"},{"ns792"}};
    encryptIDS(login_ids);
    return 0;
}



 void encryptIDS(char login_ids[5][6])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    int alphabet_count = 0;
    int numbers_count = 0;
    char lower_case[27] = {'a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    char numbers[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
        '9'};
    char encrypted_string[5][6] = {0};
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            alphabet_count = 0;
            numbers_count = 0;
            stop = 0;
            while (stop == 0)
            {
                if (login_ids[j][i] == lower_case[alphabet_count])
                {
                    encrypted_string[j][i] = ((((login_ids[j][i]-'a')+7)%26)+'a');
                    stop = 1;
                }

                if(numbers_count < 10)
                {
                    if (login_ids[j][i] == numbers[numbers_count])
                    {
                        encrypted_string[j][i] = ((((login_ids[j][i] - '0')+7)%10)+'0');
                        stop = 1;
                    }
                }

                alphabet_count++;
                numbers_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[0]);
    printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[1]);
    printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[2]);
    printf("debug : %s\n", encrypted_string[3]);
    printf("debug : %s", encrypted_string[4]);
}
```

OUTPUTS

```
debug : cj803
debug : qj257
debug : js941
debug : at038
debug : uz469
```

The issue was with the index into numbers, when the letter took more than 10 iterations to find a match.  I re-arranged the while loop logic to prevent the out of bounds index, is this the result you were expecting?

**EDIT** I copy/pasted your code into codechef.com/ide to fix it, but i didnt fix all of the formatting/indenting.  You should fix the formatting on your own prior to posting next time (just an FYI for the people who answer you).

Comment: still a surprise to see an alphabet with 27 letters

Comment: I would recommend to change the interface to the encrypt function. Instead of passing a fixed sized array it should just encrypt one string. It's much more flexible, you can change the number of strings to encrypt easily. It's simple to implement since it reduces the complexity of the function. It can be made compatible with the assignment with a wrapper function that takes the 2d-array and calls the encrypt function for each array member. Factorize this!